# Why am I getting this bad input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to create code which two users input their names, if the length of the strings is an even number then the strings are printed, if the length of the strings are an odd number then the strings will not print their names.

```
#Creating the inputs 

first_input = input('Please insert your first name:')

second_input = input('Please insert your last name:')

if:
    if len(first_input)%2==0:
        print('first_input')
    if len(second_input)%2==0:
        print('second_input')
else:
    print('The name cannot be printed')
```

Output
Line 7: SyntaxError: bad input (':')

Comment: `if:` ... If what? You need a condition there.

Comment: Yep, thank you that helped, its now printing correctly if I remove the first if statement

Answer (score 0):

Your IF statement isn't clear.

Try with this

```
first_input = input('Please insert your first name:')

second_input = input('Please insert your last name:')

if len(first_input)%2==0:
  print(first_input)
if len(second_input)%2==0:
  print(second_input)
```

You can add the ELSE clause for each of these IF according to your logic

Answer (score 0):

is because you are not passing a condition to evaluate on the first if statement

```
if:    <------------This if statement doesn't have a condition 
    if len(first_input)%2==0:
         print('first_input')
    if len(second_input)%2==0:
        print('second_input')
else:
    print('The name cannot be printed')
```

try this:

```
first = input('first name ')
second = input('second name ')

if (len(first)%2 == 0 and len(second)%2 == 0 ):
    print("the string is printed ", first , " ", second) 
else:
    print("the string cannot be printed")
```

output

```
first name carlos
second name even
the string is printed  carlos   even
```

second test
    first name carol
    second name noteven
    the string cannot be printed